# How to get the default member for Ms Access objects (or any other in VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-access

How can I get the name of the default member of an VBA-Object, that is used with then Bang-Operator (!)?

MS Docs, don't tell me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it here:

https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/03/15/vba-trap-default-members/

Solution:

- Go to the Editor (ALT+F11)
- Go to Object Explorer (F2)
- Find the Object in the List
- The default member has a blue circle in front

[image]